# Add list values to dictionary of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of lists:

```py
my_dict = {'Name': ['John', 'Peter', 'Greg'], 'Age': [26, 39, 48]}
```

I want to add new values from a flat list to each key of the dictionary:

```py
new_row = ['Bob', 23]
```

So the final dictionary would look like this:

```py
{'Name': ['John', 'Peter', 'Greg', 'Bob'], 'Age': [26, 39, 48, 23]}
```

What's the most efficient and smartest way to do this, preferably without relying on imported modules?

This would work, but is there a better way?

```py
i = 0
for k in my_dict.keys():
    my_dict[k].append(new_row[i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: Come up with **a** way first, then bother about efficient and smart. What have you come up with? Why do you suppose it's inefficient / stupid?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered so iterating the keys that way won't always give the desired result.

Comment: What would be the result if "new_row" has more elements than number of keys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `zip` the values of the dict with the list.

```
for l, x in zip(my_dict.values(), new_row):
    l.append(x)
```

You could also use a dictionary comprehension to create a new dict without modifying the original.

```
new_dict = {k: v + [x] for (k,v), x in zip(my_dict.items(), new_row)}
```

Comment: Yes! I was sure this could be done with a comprehension, but I couldn't get my head around it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `append` for the values in keys `Name` and `Age` since both of them are lists, and lists are mutable

```py
my_dict['Name'].append(new_row[0])
my_dict['Age'].append(new_row[1])
my_dict
Out[27]: {'Name': ['John', 'Peter', 'Greg', 'Bob'], 'Age': [26, 39, 48, 23]}
```

Comment: Yes, of course, but I want to build a function that doesn't know the keys. So I could indeed iterate each key, keep a counter for the list index and do the appending, but I was wondering if there could be a smarter and faster way than that.

Comment: In that case, you should consider passing a dictionary with key/value pair, like `new_row = {'Name':'Bob', 'Age': 23]` since dictionaries are unordered so it won't always work the way you are looking for.